# Listview use ScrollListener both in activty and library

Tags: android

Im using a library (fadingactionbar) to control my listview. The problem occurs when I try to set a ScrollListener to the list. It seems like the library (fadingactionbar) also use a ScrollListener  to calculate something and when I added my ScrollListener in the activity it takes the focus and it leads to that the ScrollListener in the library does not get called at all . Which causes it to malfunction.

I would like to be able to use both ScrollListener without them interfering with each other.

If that's not possible are there any good workarounds?

Comment: Can't you edit the library's ScrollListener ?

Comment: yes I can but how am I suppose to forward the event to my activity?

Answer (score 0):

I "tweaked" the library for the same purpose. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/009595717408e7854efd) I made for this purpose. You can attach as much `OnScrollListener`s as you want, without disturbing the workflow of the library.

Usage:

```
NotifyingFadingActionBar fadingActionBarHelper = new NotifyingFadingActionBar(this)
                .withCallback(this)
                .headerLayoutResId(R.layout.place_header)
                .addOnScrollListener(myScrollListener)
                .actionBarBackground(mActionbarDrawable)
                .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_waiting_list);
        setContentView(fadingActionBarHelper.createView(this));
```